# How to calculate intermediate point?

Tags: graphing-functions

I am developing an Android application, and I am trying to develop a chart with points, but I am struggling with some (probably) basic math.

So, the point is: I am drawing a price chart, and I know that the maximum price, being 50000€ is drawn at the 0px. At the other end, the minimum price, being 20000€ is drawn at the 800px. Now, let's suppose that I got a price between the minimum and maximum like 27500€. How can I calculate the px for that price knowing the information I gave earlier?

If someone could help me with this calculation, or at least point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: There's no way to answer this question from the information given.  The price can vary arbitrarily between the min and max.  Do you know what the graph is supposed to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin by seeing you have 800 px for $(50,000-20,000) = 30,000  units$ so you have $\frac{800}{30000} \frac {p}{unit}$. Since 50,000 is your zero mark, it simply becomes $px = \frac{800}{30000}*(50,000-Price) $

So for Price = 27500, you have $px = \frac{8}{300}*(50,000-27,500) = 600px$

Answer (score 1):

In general, let the minimum price be $a$ and the maximum price be $b$.  Suppose the minimum price is to be plotted at coordinate $y_a$ and the maximum price plotted at coordinate $y_b$.

So in your case, $a = 20000$, $b = 50000$, $y_a = 800$, and $y_b = 0$.

Then suppose you have a third price, say $c$, satisfying $a < c < b$.  In your case, $c = 27500$.  You want to find the coordinate $y_c$ such that $c$ is plotted to scale.  Then we require $$y_c = \frac{c-a}{b-a} y_b + \frac{b-c}{b-a} y_a.$$  Substituting, you get $y_c = 600$.